# Fitting a histogram with python

Tags: python, histogram, curve-fitting

I have a histogram

```
H=hist(my_data,bins=my_bin,histtype='step',color='r')
```

I can see that the shape is almost gaussian but I would like to fit this histogram with a gaussian function and print the value of the mean and sigma I get. Can you help me?

Comment: "fit this histogram with a gaussian function"?  Usually we just compute the mean and standard deviation of the histogram directly.  What do you mean by "fit this histogram with a gaussian function"?

Comment: how can you compute the mean and standard deviation "directly". What if the histogram is not really a gaussian and I want to fit it, let's say, with a log-normal distribution?

Comment: There are equations for the mean and standard deviation of any set of data points regardless of their distribution.  And any curve (such as a straight line y = mx + b) can be fit to any set of data.  You will need to read up on basic statistical functions (mean, median, mode, variance, ...) and least-squares approximation.  Understand curve fitting for basic (linear and quadratic) functions first before trying it out on more complex curves.

Comment: Curve fitting is not actually required, if you've got the data. Just find the mean and the standard deviation, and plug them into the formula for the normal (aka Gaussian) distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: The mean of a histogram is `sum( value*frequency for value,frequency in h )/sum( frequency for _,frequency in h )`.  The standard deviation is equally simple -- but a bit long for a comment.  Can you please **update** the question to explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ThomasK: BTW, finding the mean and standard deviation is actually curve fitting for a Gaussian distribution (and is the optimal fitting mechanism in certain senses).

Answer (score 83):

Here you have an example working on py2.6 and py3.2:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data from a text file. One number per line
arch = "test/Log(2)_ACRatio.txt"
datos = []
for item in open(arch,'r'):
    item = item.strip()
    if item != '':
        try:
            datos.append(float(item))
        except ValueError:
            pass

# best fit of data
(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(datos)

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(datos, 60, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf( bins, mu, sigma)
l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=2)

#plot
plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Histogram\ of\ IQ:}\ \mu=%.3f,\ \sigma=%.3f$' %(mu, sigma))
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I want to do this to my dataset, without scaling, thus getting my data's sigma.. Not some scaled sigma!

Comment: @user2820579 What do you mean with the "fitting of the height" ? This post perfectly answers the question on the OP. If it doesn't fit your particular problem, make a new question, but do not downvote a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the `(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(datos)`.

Comment: Is this a Guassian fit?

Comment: @JamesWarner, Yes, use data parameters to draw the line for a normal distribution

Comment: For the Histogram plot, I would label the Y axis as density or frequency rather than probability to avoid the wrath of Statisticians. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105456

Comment: Because of deprecation issues, "scipy.stats.norm.pdf" is preferable instead of "mlab.normpdf"

Comment: @MossaNova you can read how the norming is done in the docs (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). Bascially you just need to multiply the normpdf-values by `sum of all your bin-heights` * `bin-width`

Comment: "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.mlab' has no attribute 'norm'": Use `from scipy.stats import norm` and `norm.pdf()` instead

Answer (score 30):

Here is an example that uses scipy.optimize to fit a non-linear functions like a Gaussian, even when the data is in a histogram that isn't well ranged, so that a simple mean estimate would fail.  An offset constant also would cause simple normal statistics to fail ( just remove p[3] and c[3] for plain gaussian data).

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import loadtxt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

fitfunc  = lambda p, x: p[0]*exp(-0.5*((x-p[1])/p[2])**2)+p[3]
errfunc  = lambda p, x, y: (y - fitfunc(p, x))

filename = "gaussdata.csv"
data     = loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1,delimiter=',')
xdata    = data[:,0]
ydata    = data[:,1]

init  = [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

out   = leastsq( errfunc, init, args=(xdata, ydata))
c = out[0]

print "A exp[-0.5((x-mu)/sigma)^2] + k "
print "Parent Coefficients:"
print "1.000, 0.200, 0.300, 0.625"
print "Fit Coefficients:"
print c[0],c[1],abs(c[2]),c[3]

plot(xdata, fitfunc(c, xdata))
plot(xdata, ydata)

title(r'$A = %.3f\  \mu = %.3f\  \sigma = %.3f\ k = %.3f $' %(c[0],c[1],abs(c[2]),c[3]));

show()
```

Output:

```
A exp[-0.5((x-mu)/sigma)^2] + k 
Parent Coefficients:
1.000, 0.200, 0.300, 0.625
Fit Coefficients:
0.961231625289 0.197254597618 0.293989275502 0.65370344131
```

[image: gaussian plot with fit]

Comment: I am wondering why i get very different fits when using your function and the one joaquin proposes? see my related question for details.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630658/difference-scipy-stats-norm-mlab-normpdf-and-fitting-gaussian

Answer (score 10):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library provides the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module.

The `NormalDist` object can be built from a set of data with the [`NormalDist.from_samples`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist.from_samples) method and provides access to its *mean* ([`NormalDist.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist.mean)) and *standard deviation* ([`NormalDist.stdev`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist.stdev)):

```
from statistics import NormalDist

# data = [0.7237248252340628, 0.6402731706462489, -1.0616113628912391, -1.7796451823371144, -0.1475852030122049, 0.5617952240065559, -0.6371760932160501, -0.7257277223562687, 1.699633029946764, 0.2155375969350495, -0.33371076371293323, 0.1905125348631894, -0.8175477853425216, -1.7549449090704003, -0.512427115804309, 0.9720486316086447, 0.6248742504909869, 0.7450655841312533, -0.1451632129830228, -1.0252663611514108]
norm = NormalDist.from_samples(data)
# NormalDist(mu=-0.12836704320073597, sigma=0.9240861018557649)
norm.mean
# -0.12836704320073597
norm.stdev
# 0.9240861018557649
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution using only `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy` packages.
It works only for Gaussian fitting. It is based on [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Continuous_distribution.2C_continuous_parameter_space) and have already been mentioned in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447262/fitting-a-gaussian-to-a-histogram-with-matplotlib-and-numpy-wrong-y-scaling).
Here is the corresponding code :

```
# Python version : 2.7.9
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# For the explanation, I simulate the data :
N=1000
data = np.random.randn(N)
# But in reality, you would read data from file, for example with :
#data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")

# Empirical average and variance are computed
avg = np.mean(data)
var = np.var(data)
# From that, we know the shape of the fitted Gaussian.
pdf_x = np.linspace(np.min(data),np.max(data),100)
pdf_y = 1.0/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*var)*np.exp(-0.5*(pdf_x-avg)**2/var)

# Then we plot :
plt.figure()
plt.hist(data,30,normed=True)
plt.plot(pdf_x,pdf_y,'k--')
plt.legend(("Fit","Data"),"best")
plt.show()
```

and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YhQx.png) is the output.

Answer (score 4):

I was a bit puzzled that `norm.fit` apparently only worked with the expanded list of sampled values.  I tried giving it two lists of numbers, or lists of tuples, but it only appeared to flatten everything and threat the input as individual samples.  Since I already have a histogram based on millions of samples, I didn't want to expand this if I didn't have to. Thankfully, the normal distribution is trivial to calculate, so...

```
# histogram is [(val,count)]
from math import sqrt

def normfit(hist):
    n,s,ss = univar(hist)
    mu = s/n
    var = ss/n-mu*mu
    return (mu, sqrt(var))

def univar(hist):
    n = 0
    s = 0
    ss = 0
    for v,c in hist:
        n += c
        s += c*v
        ss += c*v*v
    return n, s, ss
```

I'm sure this must be provided by the libraries, but as I couldn't find it anywhere, I'm posting this here instead.  Feel free to point to the correct way to do it and downvote me :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it would be nice to see something like this, which I wrote up at [ENH: Accept run-length encoded data as input to functions like scipy.stats.describe() · Issue #15679 · scipy/scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15679)