# Graph histogram and normal density with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I look for graphing both normal density and histogram density from a serie df like that but don't achieve.
like link below
http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2007/resistors/histogram.gif

How to do that with DataFrame objects ?

```
>>> fd
Scenario
s0000      -2.378963
...
s0999       1.368384
Name: values, Length: 1000, dtype: float64
>>> fd.hist(bins=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first plot the histogram like fd.hist()

Then fit the normal density and plot it with matplotlob, please refer to:

[Fitting a histogram with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805552/fitting-a-histogram-with-python)

Comment: Surely but there is no automatic way ? I think it's a common need

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fd.hist(ax=ax, bins=100)
ax1 = ax.twinx()
fd.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax1, legend=False )
```

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26913361/841830 which shows the more complex case of two histograms and two density plots.