# Fitting a distribution to a histogram

Tags: python, histogram, curve-fitting

I have some data which I've plotted using sns.distplot
The x axis is the number of days a certain player is injured for:

[image]

I want to get the cdf for this distribution. It does not have to be extremely accurate but I want to run some simulations and effectively I want to have the distribution for this data, call it X. Then I want to run

```
X.rvs(1000)
```

which would give me an array of 1000 random numbers which represent the number of days players are injured. e.g. if it returns

```
array(2,35,140,3,4,6,7,23,55,63,...,87)
```

Those should represent the number of days players are injured.

Really not sure how to do this as all I have to go on is the data behind this histogram which is simply plotted with sns.distplot(data,kde=True)

Hope someone can help

data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([78,
58,
124,
62,
30,
46,
31,
34,
94,
15,
41,
18,
63,
15,
63,
31,
35,
23,
19,
19,
47,
154,
113,
29,
35,
58,
62,
93,
93,
93,
37,
31,
16,
17,
16,
17,
62,
31,
145,
116,
183,
183,
183,
93,
148,
183,
13,
160,
183,
183,
68,
15,
183,
57,
91,
183,
86,
133,
20,
183,
89,
183,
43,
30,
183,
183,
136,
183,
183,
12,
183,
60,
161,
67,
183,
40,
121,
52,
58,
183,
183,
9,
151,
183,
183,
183,
116,
9,
95,
183,
27,
16,
183,
52,
167,
12,
183,
183,
94,
65,
183,
30,
183,
19,
14,
183,
54,
37,
183,
152,
33,
22,
67,
183,
40,
17,
183,
50,
7,
183,
106,
72,
183,
183,
22,
80,
183,
183,
58,
183,
183,
183,
183,
183,
15,
183,
183,
183,
183,
127,
156,
183,
26,
183,
183,
59,
9,
183,
183,
55,
183,
183,
183,
28,
18,
51,
18,
11,
18,
26,
77,
65,
61,
19,
61,
61,
61,
30,
30,
30,
182,
54,
182,
22,
121,
26,
64,
91,
91,
15,
18,
60,
17,
16,
60,
29,
15,
31,
181,
15,
16,
120,
24,
26,
30,
28,
90,
28,
90,
27,
25,
27,
32,
28,
28,
28,
28,
180,
150,
28,
47,
51,
60,
25,
43,
9,
16,
24,
89,
15,
13,
58,
106,
16,
59,
29,
19,
22,
16,
16,
51,
52,
33,
26,
178,
148,
148,
42,
72,
28,
86,
17,
17,
56,
18,
25,
17,
28,
41,
37,
15,
81,
25,
147,
147,
8,
36,
32,
18,
37,
42,
23,
86,
38,
36,
55,
24,
15,
60,
54,
41,
18,
15,
17,
31,
146,
115,
64,
115,
25,
32,
85,
85,
38,
15,
23,
175,
175,
175,
84,
145,
18,
22,
38,
35,
21,
22,
53,
43,
22,
21,
37,
15,
19,
49,
25,
52,
28,
21,
21,
15,
172,
11,
109,
20,
22,
32,
29,
168,
168,
15,
28,
166,
16,
31,
86,
165,
15,
25,
48,
163,
56,
15,
162,
38,
19,
17,
40,
95,
160,
56,
56,
27,
48,
158,
32,
157,
157,
157,
15,
27,
37,
16,
46,
141,
141,
15,
31,
19,
52,
43,
15,
51,
39,
74,
119,
23,
15,
134,
43,
17,
15,
54,
33,
79,
133,
133,
21,
72,
17,
118,
26,
24,
15,
106,
30,
15,
53,
16,
21,
127,
127,
21,
126,
126,
33,
112,
17,
93,
33,
21,
17,
43,
36,
15,
44,
53,
110,
17,
17,
109,
17,
47,
38,
12,
16,
33,
62,
16,
77,
78,
88,
52,
69,
24,
63,
104,
28,
104,
15,
101,
59,
42,
99,
68,
74,
41,
33,
97,
96,
96,
20,
29,
30,
58,
41,
15,
95,
15,
33,
34,
25,
78,
51,
77,
15,
74,
76,
27,
76,
76,
31,
20,
47,
75,
35,
15,
74,
60,
73,
72,
39,
45,
35,
39,
70,
70,
38,
44,
51,
15,
17,
68,
68,
37,
18,
15,
15,
66,
49,
20,
65,
64,
64,
24,
43,
42,
23,
19,
20,
50,
49,
20,
49,
18,
41,
45,
15,
47,
15,
20,
15,
47,
47,
46,
15,
15,
45,
15,
16,
7,
44,
13,
32,
21,
17,
17,
25,
16,
26,
31,
41,
40,
19,
18,
39,
38,
15,
15,
37,
17,
20,
35,
35,
17,
33,
20,
20,
20,
19,
18,
17,
17,
16,
15,
15,
11,
11,
10,
7,
6,
5,
41,
15,
33,
28,
59,
182,
28,
15,
20,
49,
161,
157,
22,
8,
56,
33,
182,
26,
54,
46,
23,
27,
153,
28,
28,
29,
21,
45,
30,
60,
6,
182,
17,
83,
16,
22,
120,
30,
17,
20,
17,
19,
15,
67,
20,
9,
172,
182,
182,
76,
88,
55,
161,
154,
182,
25,
66,
16,
18,
38,
15,
141,
182,
19,
10,
23,
27,
145,
179,
46,
67,
84,
18,
17,
50,
32,
46,
16,
4,
62,
29,
47,
33,
16,
20,
141,
77,
30,
47,
77,
15,
62,
88,
50,
19,
45,
142,
22,
42,
12,
33,
60,
17,
26,
7,
12,
182,
33,
182,
15,
18,
85,
182,
31,
75,
18,
98,
23,
37,
39,
104,
182,
30,
51,
149,
47,
172,
39,
21,
43,
26,
24,
25,
56,
27,
24,
158,
38,
26,
66,
40,
38,
63,
8,
48,
10,
131,
16,
20,
14,
38,
49,
58,
130,
39,
110,
136,
40,
67,
63,
30,
27,
41,
33,
174,
34,
15,
19,
102,
28,
22,
47,
10,
18,
28,
69,
37,
16,
31,
27,
28,
32,
42,
81,
38,
26,
24,
15,
15,
37,
14,
149,
7,
64,
133,
99,
17,
39,
18,
11,
40,
26,
34,
134,
76,
13,
162,
39,
34,
41,
47,
182,
15,
36,
47,
80,
15,
15,
32,
16,
41,
182,
49,
27,
46,
48,
16,
38,
40,
35,
76,
15,
17,
39,
107,
143,
182,
15,
84,
19,
24,
87,
79,
16,
41,
20,
42,
74,
23,
8,
73,
21,
16,
93,
23,
171,
53,
93,
49,
15,
26,
23,
34,
167,
18,
90,
38,
12,
13,
15,
6,
180,
18,
36,
22,
59,
61,
91,
35,
19,
65,
110,
41,
91,
77,
125,
33,
93,
34,
15,
24,
32,
35,
88,
31,
27,
28,
182,
18,
16,
29,
50,
46,
182,
120,
33,
7,
117,
15,
11,
13,
182,
31,
41,
112,
110,
17,
69,
27,
41,
43,
40,
44,
37,
33,
8,
57,
106,
20,
22,
115,
31,
102,
39,
17,
50,
182,
9,
16,
32,
182,
50,
38,
15,
16,
31,
109,
26,
159,
182,
38,
16,
103,
32,
40,
106,
22,
105,
90,
78,
16,
88,
18,
65,
90,
38,
47,
36,
88,
61,
64,
52,
19,
46,
42,
27,
20,
147,
41,
15,
29,
26,
16,
19,
182,
38,
86,
34,
15,
13,
66,
34,
122,
182,
43,
41,
73,
41,
89,
23,
30,
53,
182,
7,
36,
90,
30,
127,
90,
43,
105,
36,
19,
158,
28,
41,
20,
29,
20,
150,
27,
23,
116,
67,
38,
20,
53,
36,
15,
15,
61,
91,
69,
48,
143,
15,
16,
20,
52,
17,
51,
86,
182,
40,
24,
111,
182,
56,
18,
40,
15,
63,
24,
34,
33,
35,
57,
15,
40,
50,
12,
17,
16,
182,
118,
23,
36,
98,
22,
156,
27,
124,
15,
61,
38,
40,
51,
18,
50,
43,
129,
182,
18,
91,
15,
30,
182,
31,
63,
31,
94,
31,
82,
34,
66,
42,
36,
42,
7,
20,
25,
26,
182,
58,
15,
115,
182,
15,
15,
87,
15,
93,
25,
66,
18,
16,
160,
91,
39,
47,
17,
54,
91,
20,
40,
40,
33,
105,
26,
28,
52,
56,
11,
52,
182,
23,
100,
15,
56,
9,
24,
145,
174,
55,
13,
39,
23,
9,
16,
182,
60,
81,
19,
182,
15,
98,
67,
7,
39,
15,
40,
182,
16,
9,
31,
8,
16,
29,
55,
53,
123,
43,
50,
28,
23,
18,
80,
15,
16,
35,
15,
98,
15,
36,
63,
23,
25,
20,
15,
63,
92,
34,
40,
152,
13,
51,
60,
36,
17,
145,
39,
24,
46,
9,
178,
21,
7,
26,
182,
22,
19,
182,
43,
71,
32,
15,
141,
50,
6,
15,
182,
11,
15,
74,
182,
19,
30,
30,
18,
25,
17,
15,
182,
38,
19,
15,
17,
77,
40,
92,
83,
16,
21,
142,
135,
19,
13,
53,
159,
39,
101,
34,
47,
17,
128,
36,
70,
74,
99,
11,
128,
48,
100,
15,
182,
28,
22,
182,
59,
12,
25,
36,
81,
21,
16,
15,
27,
57,
7,
93,
51,
37,
31,
17,
75,
41,
77,
182,
32,
24,
17,
54,
29,
23,
55,
40,
48,
15,
118,
150,
14,
65,
138,
27,
30,
46,
182,
15,
15,
98,
150,
182,
7,
182,
152,
24,
31,
154,
20,
18,
182,
7,
19,
33,
168,
29,
27,
41,
36,
24,
24,
24,
32,
33,
182,
15,
178,
55,
20,
35,
182,
85,
4,
44,
36,
15,
28,
159,
15,
16,
24,
15,
75,
76,
54,
43,
63,
59,
35,
22,
84,
32,
11,
17,
7,
30,
35,
18,
29,
182,
62,
37,
48,
31,
58,
38,
32,
19,
110,
14,
47,
20,
26,
15,
25,
34,
40,
43,
27,
27,
8,
26,
15,
182,
20,
58,
182,
7,
20,
20,
76,
32,
50,
174,
182,
113,
82,
15,
15,
57,
122,
5,
31,
32,
50,
15,
26,
15,
81,
15,
16,
6,
32,
39,
16,
162,
15,
94,
75,
182,
36,
21,
68,
33,
53,
182,
181,
80,
163,
115,
84,
150,
65,
15,
28,
70,
141,
39,
39,
40,
18,
99,
15,
93,
13,
56,
182,
162,
37,
66,
163,
15,
36,
43,
64,
15,
24,
15,
15,
21,
15,
36,
36,
23,
23,
151,
15,
18,
182,
39,
15,
34,
185,
40,
25,
182,
15,
15,
41,
18,
18,
56,
37,
32,
26,
36,
23,
17,
141,
21,
34,
18,
21,
45,
65,
98,
11,
21,
119,
34,
53,
59,
16,
15,
48,
110,
15,
33,
9,
102,
66,
60,
15,
64,
26,
59,
56,
31,
108,
17,
7,
71,
22,
19,
23,
41,
33,
16,
50,
74,
40,
15,
40,
114,
80,
71,
29,
19,
36,
15,
21,
24,
182,
19,
28,
60,
24,
56,
37,
25,
85,
78,
36,
15,
71,
54,
182,
155,
141,
2,
49,
15,
23,
131,
15,
66,
15,
22,
15,
66,
59,
51,
15,
64,
21,
182,
19,
20,
36,
55,
51,
44,
39,
16,
47,
41,
98,
127,
125,
24,
32,
182,
20,
104,
20,
48,
16,
12,
57,
55,
13,
32,
15,
52,
25,
15,
119,
18,
15,
15,
182,
53,
66,
24,
15,
172,
15,
120,
16,
45,
15,
32,
8,
22,
132,
31,
69,
13,
89,
40,
63,
53,
36,
96,
156,
39,
59,
24,
40,
24,
118,
109,
29,
21,
119,
120,
39,
36,
175,
15,
134,
26,
15,
15,
29,
26,
182,
36,
17,
71,
40,
31,
104,
43,
66,
45,
30,
37,
26,
74,
182,
35,
32,
15,
64,
152,
182,
52,
28,
182,
16,
76,
182,
8,
35,
134,
36,
15,
182,
126,
15,
15,
182,
15,
17,
15,
182,
35,
16,
39,
33,
125,
27,
29,
51,
52,
125,
63,
161,
24,
75,
52,
9,
109,
70,
100,
65,
48,
13,
182,
16,
6,
28,
16,
52,
23,
15,
111,
28,
47,
61,
61,
15,
20,
33,
166,
10,
20,
19,
31,
29,
20,
68,
138,
22,
56,
26,
15,
182,
17,
169,
33,
28,
49,
24,
20,
33,
38,
94,
15,
43,
16,
88,
15,
53,
18,
18,
50,
15,
15,
80,
53,
69,
34,
22,
105,
131,
31,
32,
32,
182,
12,
147,
157,
15,
24,
15,
30,
18,
16,
50,
63,
60,
70,
89,
19,
18,
38,
38,
167,
15,
125,
182,
178,
78,
84,
33,
41,
95,
44,
40,
17,
182,
64,
70,
68,
133,
79,
10,
60,
48,
29,
160,
20,
117,
42,
50,
128,
182,
51,
61,
35,
45,
33,
37,
35,
25,
20,
27,
15,
35,
182,
15,
15,
32,
87,
28,
19,
67,
15,
15,
43,
49,
15,
86,
6,
38,
5,
17,
77,
51,
15,
57,
30,
41,
20,
37,
75,
58,
149,
111,
51,
60,
64,
17,
99,
22,
182,
18,
15,
34,
71,
32,
182,
182,
50,
71,
17,
84,
35,
77,
29,
32,
31,
30,
13,
35,
105,
36,
60,
45,
62,
15,
88,
101,
15,
111,
85,
28,
23,
74,
61,
41,
129,
55,
42,
23,
182,
26,
16,
39,
33,
63,
16,
16,
118,
19,
34,
115,
15,
46,
20,
20,
182,
27,
28,
35,
98,
62,
56,
42,
175,
40,
86,
15,
154,
57,
15,
62,
30,
101,
58,
47,
15,
182,
182,
30,
17,
36,
82,
78,
21,
84,
24,
93,
15,
36,
19,
62,
12,
58,
48,
145,
16,
20,
20,
182,
18,
21,
10,
17,
58,
76,
25,
79,
36,
15,
54,
38,
30,
182,
30,
20,
131,
118,
18,
15,
29,
52,
15,
45,
22,
182,
24,
15,
15,
37,
33,
27,
60,
15,
27,
24,
8,
12,
15,
85,
21,
182,
37,
27,
49,
26,
7,
16,
14,
19,
33,
30,
4,
28,
60,
15,
162,
40,
39,
14,
22,
7,
47,
121,
40,
39,
15,
8,
30,
13,
150,
16,
7,
78,
30,
41,
26,
21,
65,
155,
54,
44,
85,
54,
72,
19,
21,
26,
127,
17,
4,
75,
23,
69,
44,
71,
102,
23,
21,
17,
61,
155,
27,
38,
27,
30,
107,
33,
24,
103,
61,
98,
6,
60,
22,
51,
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting a histogram with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805552/fitting-a-histogram-with-python)

Comment: What do you make of that blip at the right?

Comment: Hi, this is not a duplicate.. quite a more general case. Bill bell, what do you mean

Comment: I would say it looks like some (not-necessarily continuous) distribution that is skewed to the left, and that all values of injury duration beyond about 180 have been 'lumped' into a single value. And you don't wan't to sample from a continuous range at all, ie, any number from 0 to 180 such as 75.3. You actually want integers in your sample; you want to sample from discrete distribution, a mass function.

Comment: I mean that it doesn't make sense that a whole lot of players have injury durations of about 180 days. :)

Comment: You want a 'smoother' histogram. But you want to retain that blip on the right.

Comment: I think you've implied that you don't have the numbers that were used to make that diagram?

Comment: I think it may make sense as in that a whole lot players got serious injuries. That doesn't matter anyway, I have the data that created the histogram, all I have is the data such that sns.Distplot(data) is that graph, as that's what i used. The approximation does not need to be accurate, I can improge that at a later stage

Comment: I think it may make sense as in that a whole lot players got serious injuries. That doesn't matter anyway, I have the data that created the histogram, all I have is the data such that sns.Distplot(data) is that graph, as that's what i used. The approximation does not need to be accurate, I can improge that at a later stage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140110/discussion-between-bill-bell-and-user33484).

Comment: I have added the data. The graph shown is simply sns.distplot(data.values)

Comment: If you actually want the CDF, then use your data to give that as an increasing stepwise function (or a smooth version of that if you want), rather than the PDF from the binned histogram.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Effectively I want that kde that's showing, or something thereabouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the raw data it's fairly easy to provide a reasonable approximation.

```
from scipy import stats

p_data = [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 19, 11, 12, 7, 11, 12, 16, 7, 176, 62, 55, 44, 38, 48, 29, 28, 29, 35, 22, 32, 30, 36, 22, 33, 30, 30, 35, 20, 24, 33, 22, 28, 27, 32, 28, 13, 20, 9, 11, 12, 21, 13, 12, 18, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 15, 8, 14, 11, 19, 14, 11, 14, 12, 10, 12, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 5, 3, 10, 8, 10, 10, 8, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 7, 9, 2, 12, 5, 4, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 148]
thesum=sum(p_data)

p_data = [_/thesum for _ in p_data]

x_k = range(1, 1+len(p_data))
custom = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(x_k, p_data))

R = custom.rvs(size=1000)

print (R[:20])
```

First I used `Counter` from `itertools` to count how many times each duration occurred. As might be expected, some durations do not occur in the data and were represented as zero counts. Bearing in mind the operative word 'approximate' I felt justified in replacing the few zero values with numbers that are close to the neighbouring values. The results are what you see in `p_data`. Then I normalise (to make values sum to one as probabilities).

There was a dribble of values at the right end, from about 180 days on up. I put all this mass at 180 days. There was no mass at zero days. This explains why `x_k` runs from one through 180 inclusive.

Finally I use the `rv_discrete` object whose `rvs` method proves to be reasonably fast.

Comment: Thanks!! This is really great. A quick question, how would you go about if you just wanted the probabilities of getting say 42 days off?

Comment: You want the final values calculated for `p_data` (after division by `thesum`). The value for 1 days off is the 1st item, `p_data[0]`, the value for 42 days off the 42nd, `p_data[41]`.

Comment: Great - sorry just one more question, Could you elaborate how you transformed the original data to p_data and why it was necessary?

Comment: The contour of these data approximates the probability mass function from which they were sampled. But they are counts rather than probabilities. Some counts were zero. I had put the counts in order. When I found a pattern such as ..., 2, 0, 2, ... I replaced it with ..., 2, 2, 2, ... so that the middle '2' would have a non-zero probability, like the other values near it. Finally, I divided all of the counts by the sum of the counts so that the resulting values would add to one, making them into probabilities. Necessary for Monte-Carlo sampling.

Comment: Why? Now, as mentioned in an earlier comment, `p_data[41]` gives the probability of 42 days off, which is what `rv_discrete` needs to construct its representation of the the probability mass function that is used generate random samples.

Comment: There are definitely more sophisticated ways of fitting a probability mass function but, given the level of error that's introduced in Monte-Carlo sampling, this approach might not contribute significantly.

Comment: THanks, that makes sense but could I ask where you see those patterns? I have implemented your method directly by using p_data = list(Counter(data.values).values()) - that is, I looked at the counts for each no. of days off, and just built up p_data from those counts. I am not sure where you are getting counts as 0 for example. [my counter is from collections]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140184/discussion-between-bill-bell-and-user33484).