# Plotting two theoretical PDFs with each two histogram data set

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to fit two histogram with two PDF curves using the following code (from [Fitting a histogram with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7805552/2564301)):

```
datos_A = df['KWH/hh (per half hour) ']
datos_B = df['Response KWH/hh (per half hour) ']
(mu_A, sigma_A) = norm.fit(datos_A)
(mu_B, sigma_B) = norm.fit(datos_B)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist([datos_A , datos_B], 16, normed=1)
y_A = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu_A, sigma_A)
y_B = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu_B, sigma_B)
l = plt.plot([bins, bins], [y_A, y_B], 'r--', linewidth=2)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

However, I get something like this:

[image: graph with vertical red lines]

Instead of two PDF lines for each histogram, I get those vertical lines. I have tried to fix this in many ways but I still cannot figure it out.

After adjusting my code I am getting this two lines, however, they are not smooth curves.

[image: graph with straight lines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `plt.plot` plots each curve row wise. Which means according to your example it plots n vertical lines since the x coordinates are `(bins[i], bins[i])` for all lines.

To fix this change the line:

```
l = plt.plot([bins, bins], [y_A, y_B], 'r--', linewidth=2)
```

to:

```
l_A = plt.plot(bins, y_A, 'r--', linewidth=2)
l_B = plt.plot(bins, y_B, 'b--', linewidth=2)
```

OR:

```
l = plt.plot(bins, np.stack([y_A, y_B]).T, '--', lw=2)
```

**EDIT**:

To get smoother lines, you can resample the bins like so:

```
N_resample = 100
bins_resampled = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), N_resample)
y_A = mlab.normpdf(bins_resampled, mu_A, sigma_A)
y_B = mlab.normpdf(bins_resampled, mu_B, sigma_B)
l = plt.plot(bins_resampled, np.stack([y_A, y_B]).T, '--', lw=2)
```

Comment: It solved the problem, however, I would like a smother line, because this looks more that different straight lines joined rather than one whole curve. I edited the picture to clarify the question

Comment: You have one point per bin. If you want more, you need to resample the bins.

Comment: I only want 16 bins for the histogram, but is it possible to define a different number of bins for the curve?