# Best fit to a histogramplot Iris

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scipy.stats, iris-dataset

I want to plot the best fit line to every Iris class per feature histogram plot.
I have tried the solutions from these examples: [1](https://medium.com/@avulurivenkatasaireddy/exploratory-data-analysis-of-iris-data-set-using-python-823e54110d2d) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805552/fitting-a-histogram-with-python), but dont get the result i want.

This is how the histogram looks like now, and how I want them to look, but with an best fit line per class.[image: Imgae]

Here is the code that I have used to achive this.

```
def load_data(path):
    data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',')
    return data 

#the reason I have imported it like this is because I needed it on this form for something else.
tot_data = load_data(Iris.csv)
setosa = load_data(path_setosa)    
versicolor = load_data(path_versicolour,)
virginica = load_data(path_virginica)
split_data_array = [setosa,versicolor,virginica]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows= 2, ncols=2, sharex='col', sharey='row')#basis for subplots
colors= ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black'] #colors for histogram



for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):#loop through every feature
    for label, color in zip(range(len(iris_names)), colors): #loop through every class
        _,bins,_ = ax.hist(data[label][features[i]], label=iris_names[label], color=color, stacked=True,alpha=0.5)
        b = np.arange(50)
        
    ax.set(xlabel='Measured [cm]', ylabel='Number of samples') #sets label name
    ax.label_outer() #makes the label only be on the outer part of the plots
    ax.legend(prop={'size': 7}) #change size of legend
    ax.set_title(f'Feature {i+1}: {features[i]}') #set title for each plot
    #ax.grid('on') #grid on or off
    
#plt.savefig('histogram_rap.png',dpi=200)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best fit line"?  A vertical line for the mean value of each class? Or the median? Or something completely different?

Comment: @JohanC I would like the line in example 1 where he has plotted the histograms but in one figure and with the  legends in every subplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With seaborn you can add a [kde curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) via `sns.histplot(..., kde=True)`. Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
import pandas as pd

sns.set()
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
# make the 'species' column categorical to fix the order
iris['species'] = pd.Categorical(iris['species'])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
for col, ax in zip(iris.columns[:4], axs.flat):
    sns.histplot(data=iris, x=col, kde=True, hue='species', common_norm=False, legend=ax==axs[0,0], ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with kde]

Some parameters of [`sns.histplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html):

- `common_norm=`: when `True` (default) scaled down each curve (or histogram) depending on the number of rows belonging to each hue value
- `stat=`: one of “count”`,` “frequency”`,` “density”`,` “probability”`; determines how the y-axis gets scaled
- `multiple=`: `“layer”`: default, all on the same spot;`“dodge”`: bars next to each other; `“stack”`: bars and/or curves stacked; `“fill”: for each x-value the bars (and/or curves) are stacked to sum to` 1`.

Comment: is it possible to get the "legend" in every sub figure?

Comment: Just use the default, or change `legend=ax==axs[0,0]` to `legend=True`. I removed them to avoid cluttering the plot with repeated information.